# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'array' was corrupted. occurred. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, stack, runtime-error

The code will compile, but I gets a error saying the stack around the array was corrupted. I am mainly wanting to get what is in the main() to do a loop, but this error is making it just copy the same thing down instead of repeating the procedures. I am not sure how to fix the error, (I am pretty new to C++)

```
int main(void)
{

    int array[10];
    fillArray(array, 10, 1, 100);

    srand(time(NULL));
    int kthElement = 1 + (rand() % 10);

    int largestElem;
    largestElem = findKthLargest(array, 10, kthElement);

    cout << "The largest element is " << largestElem << "\n" << "\n";

    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int list[], int numElements, int minNum, int maxNum)
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        list[i] = minNum + (rand() % maxNum);
    }

    return;
}

int findKthLargest(int list[], int size, int element)
{
    int largest;
    int comparisons = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        largest = list[i];
        int largestLocation = 1;

        for (int j = 2; j < size - (i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (list[j] > largest)
            {
                largest = list[j];
                largestLocation = j;
                comparisons++;
            }
        }
        swap(list[size - (i - 1)], list[largestLocation]);
    }
    cout << "Number of comparisons: " << comparisons << "\n";


    return largest;
}
```

Comment: When `i` is `1` (on the first run through the `for` loop in the `findKthLargest` function), the `swap(list[size - (i - 1)], list[largestLocation]);` line will be attempting to access `list[size]` ... this is out-of-bounds.

Comment: You're ignoring `list[0]` as a candidate for `largest`, and if `size` is 1, you're returning an indeterminate value.

Comment: Also, there is usually no point in calling `srand` more than once.

Comment: *The code will compile, but I gets a error* -- Please note that code compiling without error only means there are no syntax errors.  It does not mean the program has no bugs or will perform the goal you are seeking.  For example, if I asked you to write a program to add two numbers, but instead the program subtracted two numbers, the program will compile without error.  But is the program correct, i.e. did it do its job it's supposed to do?

Comment: @AdrianMole Im confused on how to fix that line, because there will always be a point where it will attempt to access list[size]

Comment: @Laurie -- FYI, C++ already has a function to do what you are trying to achieve.  See [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).  Look at the example program at that link, where it gets the kth largest element, all in one line.  In your case `std::nth_element(array, array + 10, greater<int>());`